# Page is not valid in codebehind but none of validators shows any error

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have an .aspx page using vb.net  and several validators on it. When i run the page, in code behind Page.IsValid is false, but there is no any error from validators, nor in validation summary. How can i find which validator has an error, or how can i fix that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code in the ASPX page, it will be easier to help.

Comment: i wanted it, but it's about 500 lines :S

Comment: OK, post a control, along with the validation control you have used..it doesn't need to be the whole markup.

Answer (score 3):

This code helps you to find invalid validator on Page:

```
string invalidValidatorID = "";
System.Web.UI.ValidatorCollection validators = this.Page.Validators;
int count = validators.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (!validators[i].IsValid)
    {
        string invalidValidatorID = ((System.Web.UI.Control)validators[i]).ClientID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't enough information here, take a look at ASP.NET [RequiredFieldValidators](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_reqfieldvalidator.asp).

- Make sure you have the validator with the `ControlToValidate` property matching your `control Id`
- Make sure you have the correct `Display` on the control
- Make sure `EnableClientScript` is set to `true`, make sure you have an `ErrorMessage` set up.